# com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.class

Tags: android, build.gradle

This is gradle.build file and throwing the error with kitkat 4.4.2. However its working with Nought, Mashmallow and lollipop

```
- The code used in gradle file
- The code block is supporting higher versions than kitkat but not supporting with kitkat
```

How to solve the compatibility issues to support with kitkat

```
android {
        compileSdkVersion 26
        buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
        useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.deneebo.ffconnect"
            minSdkVersion 16
            targetSdkVersion 26
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            multiDexEnabled true
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
            vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
        dexOptions {
            javaMaxHeapSize "4g" //specify the heap size for the dex process
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        })
        compile('org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.android.service:1.0.2') {
            exclude module: 'support-v4'
        }
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
        compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
        compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.7'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.3.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
    }`
```

Answer (score 1):

> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:

Rectify your `build.gradle` section .

```
dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        })

        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
        compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
        compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.7'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.3.1'
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
        compile group: 'org.eclipse.paho', name: 'org.eclipse.paho.android.service', version: '1.0.2'
    }
```

Then **`Clean-Rebuild`** and **Run** .

Comment: #DeKaNszn Thanks .

Comment: thanks for your reply, i did like this, but not work.

Comment: Support v7 library includes v4 library right? then why should you enter both libraries? @IntelliJAmiya

Comment: v7 includes the v4 support library . @BhuvaneshBs Thanks for knocking !

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I fixed the issue by deleting android-support-v4.jar file  in app lib folder

Comment: @nagamuru I told you .